# how to achieve caching the data of web services locally retrieve back in iPhone Application?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, afnetworking

I'm new for iOS, i'm using AF-Networking framework for fetching the web services and successfully getting the data and loading it to the UI elements now what's my issue is Application performance is slow and it's loading form the web service every time i want to cache the images and data locally  and increase the performance of the application can anyone out there can help me with the proper solution.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In AFNetworking caching functionality is already provided by NSURLCache and any of its subclasses.Check this link http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/02/20/afimagecache-vs-nsurlcache/

Comment: I Suggest you to use Core Date, copy web service data to your core data entity and use it.your performance become much better. http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Comment: @Ganesh : Yeah i went through that link previously but dint find how exactly to achieve it can u elaborate if you're aware of it .!

Comment: @MDavid: ya i can use Core Data that but mine is a small application do i want to use core data or caching is enough can u advice id you are aware of this ?

Comment: Is the server telling your client "do not cache this"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are talking about has nothing to do with `NSURLCache` but to save the previous network request data locally. Then next time before you send a network request you can read from local file first

There are many different ways of saving data locally like Core Data NSKeyedArchiver plist FMDB. Here is my way using NSKeyedArchiver.
(put the interface here you can read the implementation at this link https://github.com/dopcn/HotDaily/blob/master/HotDaily/HDCacheStore.m)

```
@interface HDCacheStore : NSObject

+ (HDCacheStore *)sharedStore;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray *mainListCache;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray *funinfoListCache;
- (BOOL)save;

@end
```

in XXXAppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application //Or some other place
{
    if ([[HDCacheStore sharedStore] save]) {
        NSLog(@"save success");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"save fail");
    }
}
```

Comment: "I think what you are talking about has nothing to do with NSURLCache but to save the previous network request data locally. ". That is EXACTLY what NSURLCache DOES.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I thought `NSURLCashe` is just some kind of in-memory cache. But just find out in documentation "It provides a composite in-memory and on-disk cache". I'll update the answer later

Comment: @dopcn : if we use this caching is not required ? and em trying out this ll get back if i face any error

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use NSUserDefaults, follow the following

1: create NSArray of the data u need

2: Save into NSUserDefaults with a key

3:  Now you are able to use that NSArray in every class of the application

4: if you want update data simply again save into NSUserDefaults with old key

So you don't need to download data every time, just download once and save into NSUserDefaults and use.
if there is problem in saving data in NSUserDefaults then look at code bellow

**To store the information:**

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:arrayOfImage forKey:@"tableViewDataImage"];
[userDefaults setObject:arrayOfText forKey:@"tableViewDataText"];
```

**To retrieve the information:**

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *arrayOfImages = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"tableViewDataImage"];
NSArray *arrayOfText = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"tableViewDataText"];
// Use 'yourArray' to repopulate your UI
```

Comment: no need to declare in AppDelegate.before you are calling web service, you can retrieve data from user defaults if data is nill then you can call new service and if data is not nill then you can load local data from user defaults.